# best approach database design if tables has same columns?

Tags: database

My question just is simple. I can explain with image. I will create a database and this **ALL tables** of database same columns (IsDeleted,IsActive,CreatedDate,UpdateDate,CreatedUserId etc.) What is best approach desing that database ?  Should i desing like first table that all tables has same columns or like second desing that **ALL tables** relation to a base table ?

just a sample
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First approach is more suitable in your case.

Comment: You should keep all fields that belongs to User in the user table.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see a reason why you'd go with the second design unless your Selecting and Echoing does not include the UserID and Name.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should keep all fields that belong to `User` in the `User` table, with a few exceptions:

- optionality; if there are a set of fields that only apply to a subset of users, you may have a one-to-one table that is separated from User because it would not be useful for most users. For example, if you had an `Employee` table that included details only applicable to managers, you could split off a `Manager` table with only that manager-specific information.
- readability of having very many fields that are one-to-one with `User`: if this is a concern, you might split `User` into multiple tables that each deal with one subject about the user, e.g., user's contact information, user's billing information, etc.
- performance, e.g. your performance has slowed because you need to constantly run some update that locks the whole `User` table to access one or two values in that table. In that case you might split `User` into multiple tables so that the whole thing isn't locked every time that runs.